# Reload jstree window with new base node id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have 2 JSTree windows, the first shows a directory tree, the second showing the files (not directories) within the selected directory.

```js
var dirTree = $('#folders').jstree({
'core' : {
    'data' : {
        'url' : '/myUrl?action=tree',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id };
        }
    }
}});

var fileTree = $('#files').jstree({
'core' : {
    'data' : {
        'url' : '/myUrl?action=files',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id };
        }
    }
}});

// listen for event
$('#folders').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
           fileTree.jstree("refresh");
}).jstree();
```

The above is the current state of my code, but I appreciate the jstree call in the select will need to change somehow.

When a directory is clicked on, I wish to have my list of files totally refreshed with the contents of the selected directory node. I believe I wish to ask how I set the base node when I refresh the file window, but if you think you know of a better way of doing this let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has any other ideas, you are welcome to post an alternative answer.

My current solution is to set a baseId which is used as the id for the file window and then refreshed....

```js
var baseId = '#';
var dirTree = $('#folders');
var fileTree = $('#files');

dirTree.jstree({
'core' : {
    'data' : {
        'url' : '/myUrl?action=tree',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id };
        }
    }
}});

fileTree.jstree({
'core' : {
    'data' : {
        'url' : '/myUrl?action=files',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : baseId };
        }
    }
}});

// listen for event - could chain this with instantiation??
dirTree.on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        baseId = data.selected[0];
        fileTree.jstree("refresh"); 
}).jstree();
```